# Writing PDF Files to Azure Blob Storage From Databricks Notebooks

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I am working on saving PDFs from links to a folder in my Azure Blob Storage container. Is it possible to do this from Databricks?

Just some dummy code for privacy reasons:

```
testurl = 'https://www.testwebsite.com/test123.pdf'
response = requests.get(testurl)

with open('wasbs://storage@containername.blob.core.windows.net/Test Folder/Test.pdf','wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

I get an error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` when I run this.

Comment: Are you trying to do something as 
 https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/azure-storage.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fsspec` to connect to azure blob storage.

Install below packages.

`pip install fsspec adlfs`

And run below code.

```
import fsspec
import requests

testurl = "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
response = requests.get(testurl)

with fsspec.open('abfs://data/pdfs/sample.pdf', account_name=storage_account_name, account_key=storage_account_key,mode='wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Here, you need to give path as below.

`abfs://<container_name>/path_to_file`

Output:

[image]